# select apostrophes from Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a row cell value with two apostrophes in postgresql version 9.1 as follows:

```
col1  col2
''    1
''    2
aa    3
aa    4
```

Now i want to select those rows with '' from col1

I tried:

```
select * from table1 where col1 like '''''%'
```

but return nothing.

```
select * from table1 where col1 = ''''''
```

but return nothing.

```
select * from table1 where col1 = $$''''$$
```

but also return nothing.

```
select * from table1 where col1 like $$''%$$
```

but also return nothing.

would anyone can help?
thx

Comment: What about `.. where col1 = ''`?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE $$''%$$` works for me

Comment: @EricCheung In context, of course .. `select * from table1 where col1 = ''` should be valid syntax. Basically, I'm fishing for an odd dataview or collation issue.

Comment: @EricCheung: what is your client? It seems like you have some issue with your client doing extra escaping of your quotes.

Comment: Please add a proper answer how you solved it or delete the question.

Comment: @EricCheung Part of the purpose of Stack Overflow is that your questions help other people later. If you just say "problem solved" but you don't explain *how* or *what you did*, that helps nobody. So - please explain what was wrong in a useful amount of detail by posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't explained why your second attempt, which was correct, didn't work for you.

For completeness, here are the right ways to solve the problem you wrote about - which I suspect might be different to the problem you actually turned out to have.

- if `standard_conforming_strings` is on (newer PostgreSQL versions):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = '''''';
  ```

  There are six single quotes there. Two are the usual quotes for a string literal. The other four are a pair of doubled single quotes, since you want to find strings that are two single quotes and quotes are escaped by doubling them.
- For all vaguely modern PostgreSQL versions and settings, but non-standard:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = E'\'\''
  ```

  This uses the escape-string syntax, which is much more readable to people familiar with C-style strings.
- PostgreSQL-specific dollar-quoting:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = $$''$$;
  ```

  This uses the `$$` quoting style, which is a PostgreSQL extension. With `$$` quoting, `'` is no longer anything special, so you just write two ordinary `''` characters. Of course, you've just moved your problem to `$$`, which is why you can write:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 = $uniquedelimiter$''$uniquedelimiter$;
  ```

  where `uniquedelimiter` can be any valid identifier string.